# Points don't merge when using Mesh to Curve node

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

In blender, each spline point can only have 2 neighbors so when you extrude a point that already has 2 neighbors blender does weird things. And if the curve was generated by changing a mesh into a curve, there will be 2 splines where a point had over 2 neighbors. This causes joints to look weird when you use *Curve to Mesh* node in Geometry Nodes.

Is there a way to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add UV sphere to each vertex.

[image]